# Show listview after asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I defined a `Asynctask` function on a `Fragment` where I work with a `googleMap`. The `Asynctask` Function waits for the `fragment` to find a location, and once found it should update the content of the `listview`.
Somehow the code I wrote doesnt work and I´m not sure if it's because I dont handle properly the location check or it's because i dont update properly. Here is the code:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .addApi(AppIndex.API)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_stations); 
        waitForLocation waitForLocation = new waitForLocation(); 
        waitForLocation.execute(mLastLocation);//Call asyncTask func, passing "Location mLasLocation"

    }
```

`onLocationChanged` I have set this so `mLastLocation` gets updated:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       mLastLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
        //stop location updates
        if (client != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, (LocationListener) this.getActivity());
        }

    }
```

And the `AsyncTask` function:

```
private class waitForLocation extends AsyncTask<Location,Void,Location>{

    @Override
    protected Location doInBackground(Location... locations) {
        if(locations[0] !=null)return locations[0];
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Location... locations){
        List<String[]>  stations;
        stations = ClosestStation(locations[0]);


        ArrayAdapter<String[]> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your location service is on in your device settings

Comment: Why do you need an AsyncTask? Google maps already has Async functionalities for last location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need an AsyncTask

```
fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

That is already asynchronous, and it already waits for a location in the background, and it passed back in that method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   mAdapter.clear(); // If you want to "refresh" the listview
   // Just example of what to do
   List<Station> stations = getClosestStations(location);
   mAdapter.addAll(stations); 

   mLastLocation = location;
   //stop location updates
   if (client != null) {
       LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, (LocationListener) this.getActivity());
    }


}
```

You should use the `location` parameter that's passed back to you to add to an adapter.

---

And define the adapter in the onCreate, not within any async callbacks - that way you don't lose data if the methods are re-called

```
private ArrayAdapter<String[]> mAdapter;
private List markerPoints;
private List<String[]> stations;

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);

    markerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    stations = new ArrayList<>();

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations);

    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_stations); 
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Let me explain you more widely why. I have a `Fragment`, let's call it `mapViewer`. `mapViewer` is divided, half of the screen is taken by a map and the other half by a listview. On the listview it's displayed most optimal routes according to some conditions. This routes need to be calculated as soon as `mapViewer` is launched. When this happens, `mLastLocation` is always `null` so tha app crashes. The user can also click on the map and a route between where he clicked and current location is shown. Again, if i do that as soon as `mapViewer` is launched, app crashes.

Comment: `mLastLocation` will be null until `onLocationChanged` is called, yes. That's how the method works. Sleeping an AsyncTask is a poor solution to the problem.

Comment: Could you suggest a better way to do it? Because with the above code I still get null pointer....

Comment: I don't know which variable is null, so it's hard to really help.

Comment: Right. And it is assigned within `onLocationChanged`. You should never use it's value before that method, otherwise you get an exception. The one part of the question that uses it is in `waitForLocation.execute(mLastLocation);`, which I said you do not need an AsyncTask, or I do not see the use case for it

Comment: In any case, `doInBackground` is returning null in your code which is because you passed a null `mLastLocation`... Which you then pass as `ClosestStation(null)`, and that does whatever it needs to do

Comment: Exaclty, You got the point. I need to pass  to `ClosestStation()` a location, that's why I need to wait to get one. How could i do that?

Comment: What if I define all I do on `onPostExecute` on `onLocationChanged`, according to what you say, nothing will be executed till i get a proper location, right? and then i wouldn't need the `AsyncTaks` function

Comment: That's essentially what I am getting at, yes. Except the ArrayAdapter should be declared in the onCreateView for the same reasons previously mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the wait mechanism properly. Change the doInBackground of waitForLocation to this:

```
@Override
protected Location doInBackground(Location... locations) {
    while(mLastLocation == null) {
         Thread.sleep(500);//sleep for 500ms, change this value if you like
    }
    return mLastLocation;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you show some kind of a user notification (progress dialog for example) while you wait for the location to become valid.

Comment: It still doesnt work. The IDE says that `onPostExecute` is never used. Could be that related?

Comment: That means that the doInBackground never finished waiting. Does the onLocationChanged callback ever get called?

Comment: If the callBack is getting called, then see my updated answer

Comment: @Capie It should be `onPostExecute(String location)`, no `...`. That's a bad-copy paste of the `doInBackground` method

Comment: If you are familiar with android studio, what i get is `onPostExecute` in grey, and if i put mouse over it, it sais that is never used. I dont get that on debug.

Comment: @Capie The one you defined is never used, no. Add an `@Override`, and it'll complain that it isn't the correct method. Which it isn't. My last comment says what it should be

Comment: @cricket_007 You are right , just not String, i need location.

Comment: My answer was accepted. As I commented there, Sleeping an AsyncTask is a poor solution to the problem

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen the accepted answer mark. I merely fixed the waitForLocation AsyncTask, as was the question. However, your's is a solution to the problem.